# Oracle cursor loop that calls stored procedure

Tags: oracle, loops, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

how I can create a loop that calls stored procedure?
I have table that contains list of products and I want to check it against table using stored procedure.

Example table content:

- apple
- orange
- banana

In this example I want to execute this procedure 3 times using parameters: (apple, orange, banana).

I wasnt able to work it using cursor...

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur_product
  IS
    SELECT product_name FROM test.products;
BEGIN
  FOR product IN cur_product
  LOOP
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE TEST_PRODUCT( product);
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PRODUCT 
(
  PRODUCT IN VARCHAR2 
) AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE test.product_counts
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test.products WHERE product_name = &PRODUCT

END TEST_PRODUCT;
```

Comment: `execute` is not needed in PL/SQL to call a stored procedure. And parameters aren't referenced using `&` in PL/SQL either.

Comment: But you don't need a loop or a stored procedure to do that in the first place. And what use is `test.product_counts` if it doesn't store the product's name together with the count?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to place another begin end block in your for loop. Also execute immediate does not necessary for you to do the job. You do not need to use '&' when passing a parameter.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur_product`enter code here`
  IS
    SELECT product_name FROM test.products;
BEGIN
  FOR product IN cur_product
  LOOP
        TEST_PRODUCT( product);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Stored procedure(Do not forget COMMIT statement):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PRODUCT 
(
  PRODUCT IN VARCHAR2 
) AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test.product_counts
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test.products WHERE product_name = PRODUCT;

COMMIT;

END TEST_PRODUCT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur_product
  IS
    SELECT product_name FROM test.products;
BEGIN
  FOR product IN cur_product
  LOOP
    BEGIN
        -- removed execute and added .product_name
        TEST_PRODUCT( product.product_name); 
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PRODUCT 
(
  PRODUCT IN VARCHAR2 
) AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE test.product_counts
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test.products WHERE product_name = PRODUCT -- removed ampersand

END TEST_PRODUCT;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest version would be:

```
begin
    for r in (
        select dummy from dual
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.dummy);
    end loop;
end;
```

Note that you don't have to declare the cursor explicitly unless you really need a [cursor attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-D483DF0B-15DB-4466-9870-0F6E1518A40D).

Also as a rule, modern programming is not conducted in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

you can create it in test schema :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PRODUCT 
(
  PRODUCT IN VARCHAR2 
) AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO  product_counts(productCounts)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products 
WHERE product_name = PRODUCT;

END TEST_PRODUCT;

DECLARE
  CURSOR cur_product
  IS
   SELECT distinct PRODUCT_NAME FROM products;
BEGIN
  FOR product IN cur_product
LOOP
BEGIN
     TEST_PRODUCT( product.product_name);
END;
END LOOP;
END;
```

I add distinct product_name to cursor, it is because there will be no repeated product in  product_counts table. if you want to have repeated product name in that table you can omit distinct.